# Moment generating function help

Tags: probability, statistics

I am not looking for just free handout answers but I am having extreme trouble with quite a few Prob and Stat problems. My instructor likes to do proofs in class and then assign application problems, up until now I have been able to read the book to figure the work out but I cannot find these questions in the book as they are ones he posted on an online homework site instead.

The moment generating function of X is MX(t)=e^(2e^t − 2) and  Y is MY(t)=(0.2e^t + 0.8)^7. 
Suppose X and Y are independent and compute the following: Pr(X+Y=3)= ?

**I think this is a poisson random variable mixed with a binomial but I don't know how to solve it**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know that $X, Y$ are discrete random variables with support on non-negative integers only, then you may also try the probability generating function technique without reverting to the original pmf and do convolution.

Note that the probability generating function satisfy $G_X(z) = M_X(\ln z)$.
So by independence, 
$$G_{X+Y}(z) = G_X(z)G_Y(z) = M_X(\ln z)M_Y(\ln z)$$
and thus

$$ \Pr\{X + Y = 3\} = \frac {G^{(3)}(0)} {3!}$$

Of course differentiating this product $3$ times also requires some effort (hopefully not too tedious). Should be similar to the effort when you recognize the original pmf quickly and do convolution.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what this means? I'm actually not really sure what G is in this case or really any of it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function

Comment: $G$ is the probability generating function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function